# Turn .sql file into a table

Tags: database, sql, r

I have an sql file (from the following [link](http://motif.gla.ac.uk/downloads/FlyAtlas2_19.10.15.sql)).
I need to get the table which is supposedly encoded in that file.

I have no SQL experience and tried several things that have been suggested elsewhere:

1. I tried using "DB Browser for SQLite" -- I created a database and clicked "Import">"Database from SQL file" but was given an error:

> Error importing data: Error in statement #2: near "KEY": syntax error.
> Aborting execution.*

2. I tried to use R to get my table

   ```
   library(readr)
   library(DBI)
   df <- dbGetQuery(conn=???, statement = read_file("./MyFile.sql"))
   ```

   But I wasn't sure what would be my `conn` object
3. I also read suggestions to use WAMP, but it is not available for mac, which is what I am using

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 4):

This is a MySQL dump file. You can run it against a MySQL or MariaDB database. Both applications are available for the Mac.

Install either MySQL or MariaDB.

If you are familiar with the terminal, you can then enter the MySQL client:

`mysql -u username -p` (where username is your installation's username - usually "root" on a fresh installation)

You will be prompted for the installation password.

Once logged in to the MySQL client, enter:

`create database dbname;` (where dbname is the name you'd like to give the database).

You can import the SQL file by entering:

```
use dbname;
source mysqlfile.sql
```

or quit the mysql client, then enter:

`mysql -u username -p dbname < mysqlfile.sql`

Once the dump has been imported, you can either continue inside the MySQL client to interrogate the data with SQL commands or use a GUI to connect to and manipulate the database.

MySQL Workbench is such an application. Note that when you configure the connection to your database in the GUI, as well as your username and password you will need to enter `localhost` as the host name/IP. You can also create databases and import SQL files in this GUI.